# pybind11: inherit/import one module into another

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have 2 pybind11 modules, `Foo` and `Bar`

I would like to import all symbols from `Bar` into `Foo`

eg, in Foo:

```
from Bar import *
```

My first attempt was to create 2 modules (using `PYBIND11_MODULE`), and call `pybind11::module::import("bar")`  inside the module definition of `foo`:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Bar
{
    void bar()
    {
        py::print("in bar");
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    void foo()
    {
        py::print("in foo");
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(bar, m)
{
    py::class_<Bar>(m, "Bar")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("bar", &Bar::bar);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    py::module::import("bar"); // attempt to import Bar into Foo

    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("foo", &Foo::foo);
}
```

However, when importing the `foo` module in python, I get an error:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
> ```

The only reason I want to do this is to be able to separate the definitions of various different types into separate files, and then "collect" them together into a single module.

My 2nd attempt was to create helper functions which take the module instance as a parameter, and then instantiates the relevant `pybind11::class_` with the provided module instance

Eg:

in `foo.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Foo
{
    void foo()
    {
        py::print("in foo");
    }
};

void PyFoo(pybind11::module_& m) 
{
    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("foo", &Foo::foo);
};
```

in `bar.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Bar
{
    void bar()
    {
        py::print("in bar");
    }
};

void PyBar(pybind11::module_& m) 
{
    py::class_<Bar>(m, "Bar")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("bar", &Bar::bar);
};
```

in `module.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    PyBar(m);
    PyFoo(m);
}
```

This actually works!

However, having to create a helper function for every single type I want to register with `pybind11` seems a little boiler-platey.

Is there a better way to "collect" multiple `pybind11` type definitions into a single module?